# SQL QUERY to show records of names that are recorded several times and are unique towards each other

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, let us consider this table:
[In this image consists of rows of 8 where names like Mike,Glenn,Daryl,Shane and Patricia is included with their respective ages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWIO8.png)

| Id | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | 25 |
| 2 | Glenn | 19 |
| 3 | Glenn | 19 |
| 4 | Daryl | 56 |
| 5 | Shane | 30 |
| 6 | Shane | 30 |
| 7 | Patricia | 16 |

Now I want to insert the type of query that will show the names without repetitions like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8czgG.png), not like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WkD5.png)

EDIT: I entered the data from first picture. The request is to list the names without duplicates, as shown in the second and third picture but I will not convert them to text.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: If you edit the question to include relevant data instead of linking to images the question is much more likely to get answered.

Comment: I have uploaded the images, but since i am new in here, the images are all saved on imgur and they posted the link instead.

Comment: You could have copy/pasted the text. There is no need to post images.

Comment: You might want to read about how to use DISTINCT in a [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) statement.

Comment: I am quite new in here and i am still learning about this platform, i am sorry. I am trying to make the question worth understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DISTINCT specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM tablename
```

see: use DISTINCT in [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Yes i now recall how to work with it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` to achieve it.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
GROUP BY your_table.name
ORDER BY id
```

With the data you gave, the result from this query will be:

---

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | 25 |
| 2 | Glenn | 19 |
| 4 | Deryl | 56 |
| 5 | Shane | 30 |
| 7 | Patricia | 16 |

Comment: You should read: [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: I did, is there anything wrong with my answer? Please explain it

Comment: Which value should MySQL return for the column `id` (where `name=Shane`) ?  Possible answers are 5 and 6 (when looking at the picture..)   Because of this your result set is not defined, and depends on things we do not know, and might change if you install another version of MySQL.

Comment: see this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/7uPBUyjW) for the error, on a default 8.x MySQL instance